# Having trouble building an MVC application with MSBuild

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I've just installed cruisecontrol on a staging server and I'm trying to compile a solution using MSBuild. One of the projects is a MVC web application running .net 4.5. I have, of course, installed .net 4.5 on the machine. I have also deployed the site to a staging site on the same server, and it runs fine.

... but when I try to build on the command line with MSBUILD project.csproj I get the following error:

```
  (CoreCompile target) ->
  Controllers\AdminController.cs(12,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Controller' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\CruiseControl\WorkingDirectory\project.csproj]
```

It seems that MSBuild can't see any of the MVC objects such as Controller. They're certainly on the machine, and asp.net can see them or the website wouldn't run.

I'm running MSBuild from the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 directory.

Comment: in your `project.csproj`  file you have a reference to Web.MVC.dll. What is the path to that file?

Comment: No file path, just this:

    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>

I thought MVC was now part of the default .net install and not a separate install. Maybe not.

Comment: No, MVC is not part of default .Net install. Certainly not MVC5. So better have dlls saved next to your project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I need to install MVC on the build server. I had been under the impression that it was part of the framework now, but I guess it's still a separate install.